# Herbrand Logic exercise on multidimensional induction

Tags: logic, induction, natural-deduction

I am completing a self study guide from Stanfords "[Teach yourself Logic](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/public/index.php)" course, and I am stuck on a [problem](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/problems/exercise_12_05.html) regarding multidimensional induction.

"Starting with the axioms for e given in [Section 12.6](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/lessons/lesson_12_06.html), it is possible to prove that e is transitive, i.e. ∀x.∀y.∀z.(e(x,y) ∧ e(y,z) ⇒ e(x,z)). Doing this requires a three variable induction, and it is quite messy. Your job in this problem is to prove just the base case for the outermost induction, i.e. prove ∀y.∀z.(e(a,y) ∧ e(y,z) ⇒ e(a,z)). Hint: Use the strategy illustrated in section 12.6. Extra credit: Do the full proof of transitivity."

[image]

---

*Editors note: Please be aware that this course provides [show answer buttons](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/problems/exercise_12_05.html) in its questions. For this reason it will be more constructive to explain the general methods of solving all problems of this sort, rather than provide an answer.*

Comment: Do you have a link to "Section 11.6" you mention? Moreover, what is the induction scheme you mention?

Comment: Hey Luen, I have edited my answer to help you with the inductive step you are now up to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Herbrand logic course, Linear Induction if of the form:

\begin{align}
&p(a)\\
&\forall n.(p(n)\implies p(s(n)))\\
&---------\\
&\forall n.(p(n))
\end{align}

While Multidimensional induction is of the form:

\begin{align}
&\forall m.(p(a,m))\\
&\forall n.(\forall m.\big(p(n,m)\big)\implies \forall m.\big(p(s(n),m) \big))\\
&-----------------\\
&\forall n.(\forall m.\big(p(n,m)\big))
\end{align}

It is called multidimensional induction because in effect you are doing induction on $n$ for each and every $m$, which there could be multiple of.

In both forms, the goal is to find the base case, then assume a particular case, and then prove from this particular case that the next case is true. When using multidimensional induction, the assumption of a particular case is always quantified over $\forall m.\big(p(n,m)\big)$, which narrows the search of where to start.

---

In this particular example, you are asked to prove $\forall y.(\forall z.(e(a,y) \land e(y,z) \implies e(a,z)))$, this means your base case should be $(1)$, and the particular case $(2)$.

$$\tag{1}\forall z.(e(a,a) \land e(a,z) \implies e(a,z))$$

$$\tag{2}\forall z.(e(a,y) \land e(y,z) \implies e(a,z))$$

It is noteworthy that the particular case $(2)$ is the same as the thing you are trying to prove, less one universal quantifier. This is true for all multidimensional induction problems (including linear induction).

After assuming $(2)$, your goal will be to prove $\forall z.(e(a,s(y)) \land e(s(y),z) \implies e(a,z))$. This can be done by assuming its antecedent, $e(a,s(y)) \land e(s(y),z)$, then using the fact that $e(a,s(y))$ is in contradiction with premises $4$ of the question to prove $e(a,z)$.

Once this has been done, you can universally quantify over everything, and then use induction in the last step to complete the question.

---

EDIT: After your edit, you have completed the base case and are now on the inductive step.  Your goal is to prove $(3)$.

$$\tag{3}\big(\forall z.(e(a,y) \land e(y,z) \implies e(a,z))\big)\implies\big(\forall z.(e(a,s(y)) \land e(s(y),z) \implies e(a,z))\big)$$

You have already made the first step toward this goal, by assuming $\forall z.(e(a,y) \land e(y,z) \implies e(a,z))$.

The next step is to arrive at $e(a,s(y)) \land e(s(y),z) \implies e(a,z)$, and universally quantify over it. This is best achieved by assuming $(4)$, and deriving $e(a,z)$.

$$e(a,s(y)) \land e(s(y),z)\tag{4}$$

The derivation of $e(a,z)$ from the assumption $(4)$ can be made by exploiting the fact that your assumption is in contradiction with the $4^{th}$ premises. It is possible to assume $\sim e(a,z)$, then derive $e(a,s(y))$ and $\sim e(a,s(y))$.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. However, I’m not able to move forward from step 10.
1. e(a,a)     Premise
2. AX:AY:(e(X,Y) => e(s(X),s(Y)))  Premise
3. AX:AY:(e(s(X),s(Y)) => e(X,Y))  Premise
4. AX:~e(a,s(X))    Premise
5. AX:~e(s(X),a)    Premise
6. e(a,z)     Assumption
7. e(a,z)     Reiteration: 6
8. e(a,a)     Reiteration: 1
9. e(a,a) & e(a,z)    And Introduction: 8, 7
10. AZ:(e(a,a) & e(a,z))   Universal Introduction: 9

Am I on the right path?

Comment: You have the right idea, but you have taken the wrong approach to it. Your goal is to prove AZ:(e(a,a)&e(a,Z)=>e(a,Z)) as the base case. Your current method will never yield e(a,a)&e(a,Z) as the premises of an implication, but will instead yield e(a,Z), which is only half of the premises.

Comment: To do so, you must first assume (a,a)&e(a,Z), then use and elimination and implication introduction to get e(a,a)&e(a,Z)=>e(a,Z), which you can then quantify over. @Luen

Comment: Hi user400188, sorry to keep bothering you with this, but I'm having a hard time moving forward. Am I getting closer?
11. AZ:(e(a,y) & e(y,Z) => e(a,Z))      Assumption
12. e(a,s(Y)) & e(s(Y),Z)                   Assumption
13. e(a,s(Y))                                     And Elimination: 12
14. e(s(Y),Z)                                     And Elimination: 12
15. ~e(a,Z)                                        Assumption

If I'm on the right path, I don't know how to continue from step 15.

Comment: Don't forget to capitalise your Y's and Z's. I have noticed in a few of your comments that they are not capitalised, and if they look like this in the proof, then the proof assistant will interpret them as objects instead of variables.

Comment: Your next step after 12 should be to assume ~e(a,Z), then derive e(a,s(Y)) from 12. Then you should assume ~e(a,Z) again, and derive ~e(a,s(Y)) from the $4^{th}$ premises. Since you have derived e(a,s(Y)) and ~e(a,s(Y)) from ~e(a,Z), ~~e(a,Z) is true, and you will have proved e(a,s(Y)) & e(s(Y),Z)=>e(a,Z).

Comment: Also, I'm not bothered by the extra questions @Luen. :)

Comment: Based on your previous comment this is what I got: 11. AZ:(e(a,Y) & e(Y,Z) => e(a,Z))
 Assumption; 12. e(a,s(Y)) & e(s(Y),Z) Assumption; 13. ~e(a,Z) Assumption; 14. e(a,s(Y)) And Elimination: 12; 15. e(s(Y),Z) And Elimination: 12; 16. ~e(a,Z) Assumption; 17.~e(a,s(Y)) Universal Elimination: 4.
How do I reach to ~~e(a,Z)? Thanks

Comment: @Luen You forgot to leave the sub context before you made your next assumption. Between steps 15 and 16, you should make the implication introduction ~e(a,Z) =>  e(a,s(Y)). Then you can then assume ~e(a,Z) again and derive ~e(a,s(Y)) from the $4^{th}$ premises like you did before, and can introduce a negation using ~e(a,Z) =>  e(a,s(Y)) and ~e(a,Z) =>  ~e(a,s(Y)).

Comment: user400188, I updated the screenshot. Thank you so much for your help, I think I'm pretty close now. Is the next step induction?

Comment: nevermind, I just solved it! I updated the screenshot. Thank you SO MUCH for your help and patience! You rock!

Comment: No problem :) I took a day or 2 to solve this exercise the first time myself.